# Setting Up recurring profiles in drupal

Tags: paypal, drupal-7, stripe-payments, recurring-billing

I'm doing a website in drupal. It has requirement for creating subsciptions.
I have to use paypal and stripe for payment.
I have tried commerce license, but it doesn't have the feature to create recurring profiles on the payment gateways mentioned.Can anyone suggest some modules which will work for both Stripe and Paypal.

Comment: I have been scouring the net looking for a similar solution.